# Much memory usage in UITableView

Tags: ios, objective-c, memory-management, uitableview

I have an `UITableViewController` and I customize its `UITableViewCell`s. Each `UITableViewCell` contains two `UIImageViews` and two `UILabel`s. Although when I get into the `UITableView` the memory usage raises to 100 MB and i do not know the reason. Here is the code for the `cellForRowAtIndexPath` method that handles the cell customization. Can anyone help me with this issue?

```
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView 
         cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath{

    static NSString *simpleTableIdentifier = @"Cell";

    UITableViewCell *cell = 
      [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:simpleTableIdentifier];

    if (cell == nil) {
        cell = [[UITableViewCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault 
                                      reuseIdentifier:simpleTableIdentifier];
    }   

    UILabel *mnhmeioLabel = (UILabel *)[cell viewWithTag:102]; 
    mnhmeioLabel.frame = CGRectMake(mnhmeioLabel.frame.origin.x,  
                                    mnhmeioLabel.frame.origin.y, 
                                    191, 
                                    21);

    Group *tmpGroup = [mnhmeiaTotal objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
    NSLog(@"%@ ",tmpGroup.title);    
    NSLog(@"%f %f", mnhmeioLabel.bounds.size.width, 
                    mnhmeioLabel.bounds.size.height);

    mnhmeioLabel.text = tmpGroup.title;
    mnhmeioLabel.font = [UIFont fontWithName:@"Open Sans" size:10];    
    mnhmeioLabel.numberOfLines=0;
    mnhmeioLabel.lineBreakMode=NSLineBreakByWordWrapping;    
    [mnhmeioLabel sizeToFit];   

    if( tmpGroup.imagesOfArticle.count > 0 ){
        UIImageView *mnhmeioImageView = (UIImageView *)[cell viewWithTag:103];
        mnhmeioImageView.image = [tmpGroup.imagesOfArticle objectAtIndex:0];
    } else {
        UIImageView *mnhmeioImageView = (UIImageView *)[cell viewWithTag:103];
        mnhmeioImageView.image = [UIImage imageNamed:@""];
    }    

    UIImageView *markerImageView=(UIImageView *)[cell viewWithTag:100];
    markerImageView.image=[self selectMarker:tmpGroup];

    UILabel *mnhmeioDescription = (UILabel *)[cell viewWithTag:101];
    mnhmeioDescription.text=tmpGroup.constructedContent;

    mnhmeioDescription.font = [UIFont fontWithName:@"Open Sans" size:6];    
}
```

Comment: maybe the images? an image can quickly use a lot of memory.. just do the math of width*height*bit depth...

Comment: You can replace `[UIImage imageNamed:@""]` with `nil`. Otherwise you create an empty object. Also you create several font objects (two new objects per cell). Just use a static object.

Comment: You can create a custom UITableCell http://www.appcoda.com/customize-table-view-cells-for-uitableview/

Comment: Also, if your image size is much bigger than your mnhmeioImageView size, you should resize your image.

Comment: What "kind" of memory grows up to 100MB? You should pay attention only to "all Heap Allocations".

Comment: Just looking at your code you:where are you initialising labels and image views?
It looks like you are referring to them by tag which is alright once you properly initialise the labels and image view..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thank you all for your help. I had to decrease the size of each image as much as i could. This fixed my problem.

Answer (score 0):

Probably, the images are big.

Or, perhaps you are not reusing the cells properly, if you are using iOS7 and Storyboards, please follow this tutorial (Prototype cells and Using subclass for a cell sections):
http://www.raywenderlich.com/50308/storyboards-tutorial-in-ios-7-part-1

Comment: The reusing of the cells is correct.

About the size of the image he has told us nothing. But ihc think the images are not too large.